# problemas con función javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, post

Buenos días tengo la siguiente línea de código que me permite una vez que refresca mi vista con el  `$(document).ready(function () {}` rellenar campos de un formulario con javascript. la linea de codigo es la siguiente:

```
 arr = JSON.parse("{!! toJsJson( $regMiembro->persona->PadrinosPersona() ) !!}");

        if(arr != null) {

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                if (arr[i].es_externo == 1) {

                    var padrinos = {
                        id_count: 'padrino_' + count_padrinos,
                        es_esta_logia: arr[i].es_externo - 1,
                        nombre_padrino: arr[i].nombre_apellido,
                        respetable_logia: arr[i].logia_id
                    };

                    arreglo_padrinos.push(padrinos);
                    count_padrinos++;

                    $('#lista-padrinos').append('<tr id="' + padrinos.id_count + '"><td style="text-align: center">' + padrinos.nombre_padrino + '</td><td style="text-align: center">' + 1 + '</td><td style="text-align: center;"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="eliminarPadrino(\'' + padrinos.id_count + '\');"></a></td></tr>');

                } else {

                    var padrinos = {
                        id_count: 'padrino_' + count_padrinos,
                        es_esta_logia: arr[i].es_externo + 1,
                        nombre_padrino: arr[i].padrino_id,
                        respetable_logia: 0
                    };

                    arreglo_padrinos.push(padrinos);
                    count_padrinos++;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '{{ route('regMiembros.nombrePadrino') }}',
                        data: {
                            id: arr[i].padrino_id
                        },

                        success: function (data) {

                            if ($.isEmptyObject(data.errors)) {

                                $('#lista-padrinos').append('<tr id="' + padrinos.id_count + '"><td style="text-align: center">' + data.padrino + '</td><td style="text-align: center"><span class="label label-success arrowed">Propia Logia</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="eliminarPadrino(\'' + padrinos.id_count + '\');"></buton></td></tr>');

                            }
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Codigo para elimanar:

```
function eliminarPadrino(id) {

        for (var i = 0; i < arreglo_padrinos.length; i++) {

            if (arreglo_padrinos[i].id_count == id) {
                count_padrinos--;
                arreglo_padrinos.splice(i, 1);

            }
        }


        $('#' + id).remove();

        $.smkAlert({
            text: "Padrino eliminada con éxito",
            type: 'success'
        });
    }
```

Una vez que se rellenan los campos de mi formulario una de las cosas que se rellenan es una tabla destinada a mostrar los padrinos de una persona, y esta tabla es la siguiente:

```
$('#lista-padrinos').append('<tr id="' + padrinos.id_count + '"><td style="text-align: center">' + data.padrino + '</td><td style="text-align: center"><span class="label label-success arrowed">Propia Logia</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="eliminarPadrino(\'' + padrinos.id_count + '\');"></buton></td></tr>');
```

Esto se realiza bien; pero cuando necesito eliminar un padrino que dicho sea de paso su nombre es buscado por una peticion `POST` usando `Ajax` en vez de eliminar lo que hace es enviarme para la vista anterior. Cuando reviso en el inspector de Objeto me percato que pero este id: `id="' + padrinos.id_count + '"` se mantiene para los elementos que se agregan a la tabla.

Como puedo resolver este tema de integrar la peticion `ajax` con `$(document).ready(function () {}` y que no me redireccione mas la pagina. Sldos

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que usas para eliminar?

Comment: el codigo para elimanar no presenta problemas porque lo he probado con con otras cosas el tema esta en el ajax, cuando lo quito me funciona perfectamente. No obstante pongo tambien el codigo de eliminar

Comment: Seguro que esto genera bien el url: url: '{{ route('regMiembros.nombrePadrino') }}'???

Comment: si me muestra lo que solicito

Comment: En el primer if creas un link y en el segundo un button o los dos deberian ser button o debes ponerle href="javascript:void(0)" o en el handler del link le pones e.preventDefault()